# How do you get Product Variation Type fields and display modes to show up when displaying Products in a View?

Tags: views, 8, commerce

I've created a Product Variation Type for all my products, all of which have the following custom fields: *Display Title*, *Subtitle*, and *Top Rated Product?* (boolean checkbox):

[image]

When setting up a View to display my Products, I am unable to access any of these fields, regardless of whether I choose "Fields" or "Content" under "Format > Show:". Nothing shows up:

[image]

I also can't access any of the display modes I created for Products — not even the default "Cart" display mode shows up here:

[image]
[image]

Am I missing something that's required to get this working properly? I can only choose "Fields", "Product", or "Search Results", and like I said, even when I choose "Fields", I can't find any of the custom fields for my Products.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had to add a relationship to *Product Variation Type* in order for those fields to show up. Hope this helps others!